# im trying to extract some data out of html website using python

Tags: python, html

im trying to extract some data out of this page. I got the data that i wanted but i wanna sepereate it. 
I got them like this: Adresse: Veteranenstr. 21, 10119 Berlin - Mitte
I wanna get the adresse and the House number for example Veteranenstr and 21 seperated. The same goes for the light post seperated from the place. does anybody got an idea how to get them seperated?

```
<div class="article-attributes">
        <h4 class="heading">Kinodetails</h4>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span class="title">Adresse:</span>
                <span class="text">
                    <div class="first">
                        <span class="street-address">Veteranenstr. 21</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="second">
                        <span class="postal-code">10119</span>&nbsp;
                        <span class="locality"> Berlin - Mitte </span>
                    </div>
```

and here is the code that i wrote for the extracting:

```
paga_soup = soup(page_htmll,"html.parser")
karak = paga_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"article-attributes"})
ka = karak[0]
dat = ka.findAll("li")

# suche nach Adresse
for by in dat:
    adresse = by.find_all('span')
    if (adresse[0].text == "Adresse:"):
        print('    ' + adresse[0].contents[0] + ' ' + adresse[2].text + ', '+ adresse[3].text + ' ' + adresse[4].text.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, using a CSS selector to find the span that has the address, split on a space, and unpack them to be assigned to the variables. It depends on how other addresses look like you might want to tweak the unpacking a bit.

```
paga_soup = soup(page_htmll,"html.parser")
            karak = paga_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"article-attributes"})
            ka = karak[0]
            dat = ka.findAll("li")
            # suche nach Adresse
            for by in dat:
                address, number = by.find(".article-attributes .street-address").text.split()
```

Comment: You can pick as best answer if that solves your issue, thanks :)